# Visual Studio 15: Overloading "<<" insertion operator in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, operator-overloading

The below code works fine with **GNU GCC v7.1.1** but gives an ERROR with VS15

```
#include <iostream>

class Logger {
public:
    //var should be initialized in  init loge level function
    bool debug_log_level;

    friend Logger& operator << (Logger& p, const char* str);
    Logger& logs(std::string severity, bool level = 0);
    Logger& getInstance();
};

Logger logger;
Logger& instance= logger;

Logger& Logger::getInstance() {
    static Logger theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}

Logger& Logger::logs(std::string severity, bool level)
{
    //Unused(level) as init is one time activity and will use it's own variable.
    std::cout<<severity << ": ";
    return instance;
}

//will be invoked when RHS is class reference and LHS is "str"
Logger& operator<<(Logger& p, const char* str)
{
    if(p.debug_log_level)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return instance;
}

int main()
{
    logger.debug_log_level=true;
   logger.logs("Info",0)<<"Ravi..";
   return 0;
}
```

VS15 gives error : **no operator "<<" matches these operands** in function ***`Logger::logs(std::string severity, bool level)` at `std::cout<<severity << ": ";`*** line. 
 Please let me know if I am missing something which is VS15 specific.

Comment: Try add `#include <string>`.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], for example `#include <iostream>
int main(){std::cout<<std::string{};}`.

Comment: @songyuanyao: It is working. Thank you! could you please explain more about it as an answer?

Comment: I have https://godbolt.org/g/XAhDPa for the MCVE and it does fail to compile

Comment: @meneldal: Please check same code [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php). It won't fail.

Comment: @RaviShinde You just need to include all the necessary header files. GCC might include `<string>` implicitly when `#include <iostream>`, but you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which implementation is right according to the standard, but in this case it seems to be that with GCC `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::string&)`(see [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)) is implemented in a different place from in Visual Studio's STL, and is brought in when including `iostream`, while with Visual Studio only the basic implementation of `std::string` (implemented in `xstring`) is brought in.

You can fix this by adding

```
#include <string>
```

To your file (see it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/T8MJ1y))

I can't find any information as to whether implementing basic functionality of `std::string` in `xstring` (as VS) and including that in `iostream` is correct, and it seems that actually `std::string` should not be visible at all if you include only `iostream` (since it doesn't seem to depend on it). In this case, your code should also fail when using `std::string` in every place.